# Changing Part headings (color and font size)

Tags: sectioning, color, koma-script

I would like to change the color of my part headings to match the other headings (cyan); however, if I just add a line

```
\setkomafont{part}{\color{cyan}
```

The color  of the title is modified but also the  its font gets much smaller.
How can I change the color without modifying its size?

If I add "LARGE":

```
\setkomafont{part}{\color{cyan}\LARGE}
```

Still, the font is smaller.

Also, I would like to modify the prefix; right now the header reads:  "Part II. Whatever", and it is black. I would like "Part II Whatever" (without the dot after the Roman number) and cyan instead, as the rest of the headings (BTW I have seen many of you posting, besides the code, also its output, I am sorry but I could not understand how to do it).

I tried with

```
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{%
    {\color{cyan}\thepart}%
}
```

The roman number becomes cyan, the dot disappears, but also the word "part" is no longer present in the output.

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
    \usepackage{xcolor, graphicx}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{indentfirst}
    \usepackage{times}
    \usepackage{mathptmx}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \doublespacing
    
    
    \definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}
    
    \let\raggedchapter\raggedleft
    \addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
    %\setkomafont{element}{commands}
    \setkomafont{title}{\color{cyan}\LARGE}
    \setkomafont{chapter}{\color{cyan}\LARGE}
    \setkomafont{subtitle}{\color{black}}
    
    \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
        \scalebox{3}{\color{cyan}\thechapter}%
    }
    
    
    \begin{document}
    \author{}
    
    \subject{Linea Guida}
    \title{\textbf{Il trattamento laparoscopico di laparocele e ernie ventrali}}
    \subtitle{}
    \titlehead{}
    
    
    \date{Gennaio 2022}
    
    \frontmatter
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Intro}
    
    
    
    \mainmatter
    \part{Sviluppo della linea guida}
    \chapter{one}
    \chapter{two}
    \part{Quesiti}
    \chapter{three}
    \chapter{four}
  
\appendix
\chapter{AppendixA}
\chapter{AppendixB}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Try inserting `\partname` before `\thepart`.

Comment: Great! Thank you. Works nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the command:

```
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\color{cyan}\partname~\thepart}
```

includes the partname (as suggested by @Imran), adds the color to it and also gets rid of the autodot feature.

Now all three problems are solved.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I found a solution for the first problem:

Using `\addtokomafont` (insead of `\setkomafont`) added the cyan color without altering the rest of the attributes.

Now, only the "prefix" part needs to be solved

Answer (score 1):

You can set option

```
numbers=noenddot
```

to get rid of the dot after the numbers.

To change the color of the part number use

```
\addtokomafont{partnumber}{\color{cyan}}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\chapternumdepth}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% only needed with outdated TeX distributions
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\let\raggedchapter\raggedleft
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{title}{\color{cyan}}% <- changed: the font size of title is hard coded by the class
\setkomafont{chapter}{\color{cyan}\LARGE}
%\setkomafont{subtitle}{\color{black}}
\addtokomafont{partnumber}{\color{cyan}}
\addtokomafont{part}{\color{cyan}}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \scalebox{3}{\thechapter}% <- changed: font element chapter was already set to `\color{cyan}`
}


\begin{document}
\author{}
\subject{Linea Guida}
\title{\textbf{Il trattamento laparoscopico di laparocele e ernie ventrali}}
\date{Gennaio 2022}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Intro}
\mainmatter
\part{Sviluppo della linea guida}
\chapter{one}
\chapter{two}
\part{Quesiti}
\chapter{three}
\chapter{four}
\appendix
\chapter{AppendixA}
\chapter{AppendixB}
\end{document}
```

[image]